# NodeJs Error: write EPIPE http unix socket domain LXD API

Tags: node.js, api, sockets, epipe, lxd

The whole idea is to use the LXD RESTful API over a unix socket for local operations. The following code runs well once for each 2 or 3 with errors. I don't know if is related to node.js or is related the lxd api.

**The Output with error**

problem with request: write EPIPE
{ [Error: write EPIPE]
  code: 'EPIPE',
  errno: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write',
  address: undefined }

**The code:**

```
/*
Adapted from 
http://rapiddg.com/blog/calling-rest-api-nodejs-script
*/
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http'), req, response;

var socketUSD='/var/lib/lxd/unix.socket';

function RestConsume(){ };

RestConsume.prototype._doRequest_=function(httpMethod,pathAPI,data,fnCallBack){
        var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
        var headers = {};

        if (httpMethod==='GET'){
            pathAPI+='?'+querystring.stringify(data);

        }else{
            headers = {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Content-Length': dataString.length
            };
        }
        var options = {
                socketPath: socketUSD,
                path: pathAPI,
                method: httpMethod,
                headers: headers
            };

        var req=http.request(options, function (res){
            res.setEncoding('utf-8');

            var resultString="";

            res.on('data',function(data){
                resultString +=data;
            });//end res.on('data')//

            res.on('end',function(){
                console.log(resultString);
                var responseObject = JSON.parse(resultString);
                fnCallBack(resultString);
            });
        });

        req.write(dataString);
        req.end();
        req.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log('Haciendo '+httpMethod);
          console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
          console.log(e);
        });
};
RestConsume.prototype.doGet=function(pathAPI,data,fnCallBack){
        return this._doRequest_('GET',pathAPI,data,fnCallBack);
};
RestConsume.prototype.doPost=function(pathAPI,data,fnCallBack){
        this._doRequest_('POST',pathAPI,data,fnCallBack);
};
RestConsume.prototype.doPut=function(pathAPI,data,fnCallBack){
        this._doRequest_('PUT',pathAPI,data,fnCallBack);
};
RestConsume.prototype.doDelete=function(pathAPI,data,fnCallBack){
        return this._doRequest_('DELETE',pathAPI,data,fnCallBack);
};
var obj=new RestConsume();
obj.doGet("/1.0/containers/pc01/logs",{},function(data) {
    console.log('get Respuesta:\r\n' + data);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: [use the documentation](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request).

More precisely the line that says:

```
http.request(options, callback).end();
```

Now, the code works like a charm.